# How to connect Oracle Advance Queue (AQ) from Oracle ADF?

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, webcenter

How can I connect to Oracle Advance Queue(AQ) from Oracle ADF. I want to display Advance Queue(AQ) data (i.e. payload XML) in table format into a adf ui page.Is there any adapter available for that?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Message-Driver Beans (as Oracle AQ is an implementation of JMS). I think these links could help you:
[Oracle AQ with Message-Driven Beans](https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/how_to_use_oracle_aq_with_message-driven_beans_in_weblogic)  (here you'll find a sample of an ADF Fusion application)
[How to connect Oracle AQ to MDB](https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/resource/pdf/How%20to%20connect%20MDB%20to%20Oracle%20AQ.pdf)
[Using MDB with ADF](https://blogs.oracle.com/adf/entry/using_message_driven_bean_and)